# What is the locations of the registry files in Windows 2012 & Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012

Looking for the physical files the Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2 server registry. Does anyone know their location and names?

Answer (score 2):

[On Windows NT-based systems, the registry files are stored under `%SystemRoot%\System32\Config\`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#Windows_NT).  (The literal path is most usually `C:\Windows\System32\config`).

Comment: And user specific hives/files are stored in the root of each user's home directory.